# How can I standardize the URL for AW blog extension?

Tags: magento

I'm using tje AheadWorks blog extension and the URL for a post when linked from the main blog page vs a category page is different.

**For example, from the main blog page:**

```
domain.com/blog/blog-post-title
```

**From a category page:**

```
domain.com/blog/cat/category-name/blog-post-title
```

This obviously creates duplicate content issues.

I would like to force all URLs to be the same as from the main blog page, i.e.

```
domain.com/blog/blog-post-title
```

I don't know enough about Magento to try any options, otherwise I would have posted what I've already done.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I'm asking how to program this change.

Comment: Yes, but that's not a programming question. You've said "try any options" and that doesn't sound like programming to me. What is your programming-related question? If you don't have one then this is off-topic.

Comment: I said it's a programming question. Use some common sense. This is a programming forum. I'm talking about software. Stock nitpicking. Bleh, do whatever. You will anyways. People like you always do.

Comment: What is your programming question? I suspect if we knew what programming question you had then your would get answers given that this is a programming website. I'm not nitpicking - I'm curating.

Answer (score 1):

In the file `app/code/community/AW/Blog/Block/Abstract.php` you need to edit the method `_processCollection`.
The following lines (68-80):

```
if ($category && $categoryUrl) {
    $item->setAddress(
        $this->getBlogUrl(
            null,
            array(
                 self::$_catUriParam  => $category->getIdentifier(),
                 self::$_postUriParam => $item->getIdentifier()
            )
        )
    );
} else {
    $item->setAddress($this->getBlogUrl($item->getIdentifier()));
}
```

change to:

```
$item->setAddress($this->getBlogUrl($item->getIdentifier()));
```